# Efficient way to loop through spark dataframe and determine counts of column values as types

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe, I would like to loop through each column in the dataframe and determine the count of datatypes(int, string, boolean, datetype) for each column. NOT the column type overall, but the counts of each value as it's own type. So for example

```
col_1|col_2|col_3
 aaa
 bbb
 14
 16
 true
```

So the counts for col_1 would be, strings=2, int=2, boolean=1

Is there a way to do this in spark? If so, how? How do I need to convert to rdd and loop through each row?

Comment: The columns of a spark dataframe are typed. I don't believe it's possible to have a single column with multiple different types in it. Unless you are storing everything as a string, and are looking to parse the values to their expected types, this likely is not possible.

Comment: I am trying to do exactly what you just stated.  Every column is a string.   In each column, I want to parse the values to there expected types for each column.  So col_1 might have 100 strings, 25 ints, 25 booleans, etc.. I just want those counts @TravisHegner

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rudimentary example. You'll have to pay close attention to your data and the type parsing order. For instance, `"1".toDouble` will succeed, and perhaps you wanted that to be counted as an int. If you only have the three types in the question, than this code should work out of the box for any number of string columns.

```
val data = spark.createDataset(Seq(
      ("aaa", "1", "true"),
      ("bbb", "bar", "2"),
      ("14", "10", "false"),
      ("16", "baz", "11"),
      ("true", "5", "4")
)).toDF("col_1", "col_2", "col_3")

import scala.util.Try

val cols = data.columns.toSeq

data.flatMap(r => {
    cols.map(c => {
        val str = r.getAs[String](c)
        if(Try(str.toBoolean).isSuccess) {
            (c, "boolean")
        } else if(Try(str.toInt).isSuccess) {
            (c, "int")
        } else {
            (c, "string")
        }
    })
}).toDF("col", "type")
    .groupBy("col").agg(collect_list("type").as("types"))
    .as[(String, Array[String])]
    .map(r => {
        val mp = r._2.groupBy(t=>t).mapValues(_.size)
        (r._1, mp)
    }).show(false)
```

This code results in:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------+
|_1   |_2                                      |
+-----+----------------------------------------+
|col_3|Map(boolean -> 2, int -> 3)             |
|col_2|Map(int -> 3, string -> 2)              |
|col_1|Map(boolean -> 1, int -> 2, string -> 2)|
+-----+----------------------------------------+
```